# How to get size of boost SPSC Queue?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, queue, size

We would like to know the number of element in the queue at a given point of time.
We are pushing and popping objects, we would like to know the number of object in the Queue buffer. 
Is there any inbuilt function for this ?
Or some other way to get it ?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html

Answer (score 3):

You can't reliably get the size because it invites race conditions. For the same reason, you won't find the `empty()` method: by the time the method returned a value, it will be irrelevant, because it might have changed.

Sometimes lockfree containers provide an "unreliable_size()" method (for purposes of statistics/logging)

The special case here is that SPSC assume single producer and consumers:

- `size_type read_available() const;`

  number of available elements that can be popped from the spsc_queue
- `size_type write_available() const;`

  get write space to write elements

Note these are **only** valid when used from the respective consumer/producer thread.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like our operations are limited to the pop() and push() functions. In your software design, you have to focus on these operation. For example, if you are the consumer, you are limited to consume all of the items on the queue one at a time. And you have to rely on another channel of communication with the producer (conditional variable or atomic variable).

```
atomic<bool> producer_done(false);  // producer set this variable to tell the consumer the status
spsc_queue<Obj> theQ; // assume producers have pushed
Obj tmpObj;
while (!producer.done) {
   if (!theQ.pop(tmpObj)) {
      cerr << "did not get any item from the producer\n";
      // the producer may be too slow, your only choice is loop and wait, or other more complicated inter thread communication
      // may be sleep a little
      this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
   }
   else { // you got an item to work on
      consume(tmpObj);
   }
}
// now you know the single producer is no longer adding item to the queue
while (theQ.pop(tmpObj)) {
   consume(tmpObj);
}
```

This is essentially the coding patter you can use with the spsc_queue at the consumer part.